# How can I share a C++ class variable between a thread started with the pigpiod start_thread () method and the main thread?

Tags: pigpio

I've got a C++ class containing some class variable like `char some_class::current_command`. One of the static methods of this class, say `void Play ()` now calls the pigpiod `start_thread ()` method to fork a sub-thread, and then, `current_command` is used to control what the thread is doing from the main thread, until it is stopped, of course. The thread needs read-write access to the variable.

As I suspect a race condition leading to unwanted changes of the value of `current_command`, I'd like to secure it somehow. Shall I simply use a `std::mutex`, or something else, maybe `std::atomic` (as demonstrated [in answer #1 to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433551/share-a-variable-between-main-and-thread))? Thank you.

Comment: You should ask this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, but pigpiod is specific to the Raspi…!